# Try to transform object (type casting) using map operator in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

Api response (json) -

```
{
    "count": 1050,
    "next": "....",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Test1",
            "url": "https://test/1/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test2",
            "url": "https://test/2/"
        }
     ]
}
```

Interface:

```
export interface ITestModel{
  name: string;
  url: string;
}
```

Service:

```
getData(): Observable<ITestModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<ITestModel[]>(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      map((res) =>
        res.map((data) => ({
          name: data.name,
          url: data.url
        }))
      )
    );
  }
```

Error: (When I subscribe the above function in controller)

**core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: res.map is not a function at MapSubscriber.project (test.service.ts:19)**

Expectation:

1. In getData() function, I would like to transform observable as **ITestModel[]**
2. Expected output while subscribe (Json)

[
{
"name": "Test1",
"url": "https://test/1/"
},
{
"name": "Test2",
"url": "https://test/2/"
}
]

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getData(): Observable<ITestModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      map((res) =>
        res.results.map((data) => {
          return { 
             name: data.name,
             url: data.url
           };
        });
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does not working. Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ITestModel[]' There are only 2 properties id and url.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Probably not the best solution, but hopefully it works.